# Add label to existing node with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I add a label to an existing node using a Cypher query?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

That's in the reference docs, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-set.html#set-set-a-label-on-a-node, you need to use `set` to a add a label to a existing node:

```
match (n {id:desired-id})
set n :newLabel
return n
```

Comment: If you want to add a label to all nodes with another label, just do `match (n:ExistingLabel) set n :NewLabel`. The existing label is not removed.

Comment: Old labels can be removed using: `match (n:OldLabel) remove n:OldLabel`