# How to add labels to nodes using spring data neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Is there a way to add labels to nodes using the SDN node entity? I know that i could write a cypher query and add it to a stub in my SDN repository but is there maybe another way?

The @Labels annotation does not seem to work. I tried this example:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/15cc8418ed4d429a952b86f788717add8a93f76c/spring-data-neo4j-aspects/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/aspects/Person.java
(Using 3.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT)

My goal is to dynamically add labels so that i could write a more specific model later on which could be used to enhance that "type" of node in the graph.

Comment: What exactly did not work? Perhaps raise an issue on springsource JIRA with a bug description?

Comment: Better to just show you:
https://github.com/Jotschi/code-examples/tree/neo4j-sdn-labels-example


For me @Labels only works when i manually add the primary label myself.

Comment: I added an jira issue with additional information: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-541

Comment: Anyone had any further thoughts on this? Even adding it manually using Cypher would work for me! Working example anyone?

Comment: Yes cypher would work i guess:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21625081/how-to-add-label-to-existing-node-neo4j-cypher